# Could you help me find a proper adjective?

Tags: word-choice

> The car park was deserted. It was *empty/abandoned*.

I think that both r acceptable but I have to decide one.I think abandoned is better, What about your opinions?

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to describe; in context, the words can either be subtly different or extremely different.

Answer (score 1):

'Empty' and 'Abandoned' have similar but not exactly the same meaning in your example sentence. An 'empty car park' is one with no or very few cars (or people) in it (at the current moment). An 'abandoned car park' implies that no or very few people use the car park, and haven't done so for a while. The abandoned car park might also be filled with broken, abandoned cars, litter, and garbage, rather than being 'empty'.